# Code continues on for a long time - Recursion Issues - How can I fix?

Tags: java, recursion, overflow

I used the following code in my class with the intention of doing one round of recursion (specifically creating an object within an object of the same type). Well, that one round of recursion is now like 200 rounds of recursion... So that messes a lot of stuff up. The following code is where I call the recursion:

```
//Find Solute
    try{if(iterations == 0){ //RECONDITION::: iterations is equal to zero at start of program and is static!
        remaining = Whitespace.removePreceding(remaining);
        String unused = remaining.substring(0);
        InterpretInput solute = new InterpretInput(remaining);
        solute.begin();
        solute.fixSoluteAmount();
        soluteAmount = solute.getSolventAmount();
        isSolution = true;
        ++iterations;
    }}catch(Exception ex){
    }
    finally{
        System.out.println("Debugging point D");
        findNumber();
        fixSolventAmount();
        fixSoluteAmount();
    }
```

You'll find "Debugging point D" above, this is printed a ton of times so it apparently is going after the recursion with a bunch of objects, and the rest of the code is screwed up because of this. I just need someone experienced to point out how this is flawed as one iteration of recursion.

If you need the entire class, I'll also copy / paste that bellow, but it's almost 200 lines... so yeah... (I know I shouldn't make classes that long but this object needed a lot of stuff in it).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

public class InterpretInput {

```
/**
 * @param remaining - The string that was input, what's left to analyze
 */

/**  Variables  */

private String remaining; //The string input by the user, containing what's left to analyze
private static int iterations = 0;

//Solvent Info
private double solventAmount; //The amount of the solvent expressed as final in MOLES
private M solventAmountMeas; //The measurement used in solventAmount
private double solventConc; //The concentration of the solvent
private M solventConcMeas; //The measurement used in solventConc
private E[] solventCompound; //The compound of the solvent
private E[] water = {E.H, E.H, E.O};

//Solute Info
private double soluteAmount; //The amount of solute in the solution

//Type of Data
private boolean isElement = false; //Determines if the information input is only an element
private boolean hasAmount = false; //Determines if the information input has an amount of solvent
private boolean isSolution = false; //determines if the information input is a solution

private int identificationNumber;

/**  Constructor  */

public InterpretInput (String remain){
    remaining = remain;
}


/**  Mutator Methods  
 * @throws Exception */

public void begin() throws Exception{

    //Find Measurement
    FindMeasurements measureObject = new FindMeasurements(remaining);
    while (measureObject.exists() == true){
        measureObject.determineNumber();
        measureObject.determineMeasurement();
        double solventAmountTemp = measureObject.getAmount();
        M solventAmountMeasTemp = measureObject.getMeasurement();
        if( (solventAmountMeasTemp.getType()) == 3 ){
            isSolution = true;
            solventConc = solventAmountTemp;
            solventConcMeas = solventAmountMeasTemp;
        }else{      
            hasAmount = true;
            solventAmount = solventAmountTemp;
            solventAmountMeas = solventAmountMeasTemp;
        }
        remaining = measureObject.getRemaining();


    }

    //Find Compound
    FindCompound comp = new FindCompound(remaining);
    comp.getCompound();
    solventCompound = comp.getValue();
    remaining = comp.getRemaining();
    if (solventCompound.length == 1)
        isElement = true;

    //Find Solute
    try{if(iterations == 0){
        remaining = Whitespace.removePreceding(remaining);
        String unused = remaining.substring(0);
        InterpretInput solute = new InterpretInput(remaining);
        solute.begin();
        solute.fixSoluteAmount();
        soluteAmount = solute.getSolventAmount();
        isSolution = true;
        ++iterations;
    }}catch(Exception ex){
    }
    finally{
        System.out.println("Debugging point D");
        findNumber();
        fixSolventAmount();
        fixSoluteAmount();
    }
}

public void fixSoluteAmount() throws Exception {
    fixSolventAmount();
}

public void fixSolventAmount() throws Exception {
    switch (identificationNumber){ //VIEW findNumber TO SEE INDEX OF THESE CASES

        case 1:{
            //In this situation, there would be nothing to change to begin with
            break;
        }

        case 2:{
            //In this situation, there would be nothing to change to begin with
            break;
        }

        case 3:{
            solventAmount *= solventAmountMeas.ofBase();
            switch (solventAmountMeas.getType()){
                case 1:{ //volume
                    if (!solventCompound.equals(water))
                        throw new Exception();
                    else{
                        solventAmount *= 1000; //Convert 1000g for every 1L
                        double molarMass = 0;
                        for (E e : solventCompound)
                            molarMass += e.atomicMass();
                        solventAmount /= molarMass; //convert to moles
                    }
                }

                case 2:{ //mass
                    double molarMass = 0;
                    for (E e : solventCompound)
                        molarMass += e.atomicMass();
                    solventAmount /= molarMass; //convert to moles
                }
            }
        }

        case 4:{
            if(solventAmountMeas.equals(M.m)){
                throw new Exception(); //I AM TAKING OUT THIS FEATURE, IT WILL BE TOO DIFFICULT TO IMPLEMENT
                                       //BASICALLY, YOU CANNOT USE MOLALITY IN THIS PROGRAM ANYMORE
            }
        }

        case 5:{
            if(solventAmountMeas.equals(M.m))
                throw new Exception(); //I AM TAKING OUT THIS FEATURE, IT WILL BE TOO DIFFICULT TO IMPLEMENT
                                       //BASICALLY, YOU CANNOT USE MOLALITY IN THIS PROGRAM ANYMORE
            double molarMass = 0;
            for (E e : solventCompound)
                molarMass += e.atomicMass();
            solventAmount /= molarMass; //convert to moles
        }
    }
}

public void findNumber(){
    /**
     * 1 = Element
     * 2 = Compound
     * 3 = measured amount of compound
     * 4 = specific concentration of solution
     * 5 = Measured amount of specific concentration of solution
     * */

    if(isElement==true)
        identificationNumber = 1;
    else if(isSolution == false && hasAmount == false)
        identificationNumber = 2;
    else if(isSolution == false && hasAmount == true)
        identificationNumber = 3;
    else if(isSolution == true && hasAmount == false)
        identificationNumber = 4;
    else
        identificationNumber = 5;
}


/**  Accessory Methods  */

public double getSolventAmount(){
    return solventAmount;
}

public double getSoluteAmount(){
    return soluteAmount;
}

public double getConcentration(){
    return solventConc;
}

public E[] returnCompound(){
    return solventCompound;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Begin` function appears to call itself prior to incrementing the `iterations` variable.  This will cause an infinite recursion.  See my `HERE` notes in the code below.

```
//Find Solute
try{if(iterations == 0){
    remaining = Whitespace.removePreceding(remaining);
    String unused = remaining.substring(0);
    InterpretInput solute = new InterpretInput(remaining);

    // HERE - calls itself again, prior to incrementing
    // iterations variable
    solute.begin();

    solute.fixSoluteAmount();
    soluteAmount = solute.getSolventAmount();
    isSolution = true;

    // HERE - iterations is incremented, but too late
    ++iterations;
}}catch(Exception ex){
}
```

To resolve the recursion issue, you should increment `iterations` prior to the `begin` call.

Answer (score 0):

The code here is pretty messy; it's a little difficult to figure out what the goal is. What are you trying to do with the string in `InterpretInput`, and why does it take such a complex solution (recursively built objects) as opposed to a loop or even just a recursive method?

Beyond that, however, it doesn't appear that there should be any way for your recursion to break. The only valid way for it to do so is if `iterations != 0`, which is never true because the ONLY time `iterations` is ever incremented is after the recursive call. Thus, I think the only reason the program terminates at all is that you overflow the stack, but the exception is caught by the empty `catch` block. Try printing something out in that block; I bet that's where the code is going even if you don't expect it to.